# postgresql ERROR: VACUUM cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string

Tags: sql, postgresql

all I have to DO block which I am planning to run to do vacuum on tables which has dead rows from n to n
however, facing error  `ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string`

Question how to run it, I have more than 200 Schemas and more than 800 tables I need to vacuum, I can't do it on full DB or one by one that's why I was planning to do it with the cursor.

here is code

````
DO 
$$

--declaretion of varibles
 DECLARE d_date timestamp :=NOW(); -- tday  date
         t_sql text;                -- main SQL stetent  updae 
         t_simulation_Before text ; -- hold select for simulation  before 
         t_value TEXT ; -- value used to update 
         i_min_n_dead_tup integer   := 0;
         i_max_n_dead_tup integer   := 1000 ;    

 -----------------------EXECUTE FLAG------------------
 ----- do not set to = Y if not ready to deploy-------
        v_exec char(1) :='N';
 -----------------------------------------------------
 DECLARE cur_upd_text  refcursor;
  
BEGIN
  OPEN Cur_upd_text FOR -- cursor. to go over all schemas and create proper dynamic SQl statment

  SELECT 'VACUUM FULL ANALYZE '||schemaname ||'.'|| relname  , n_dead_tup
    FROM pg_stat_user_tables
   where n_dead_tup >0 and  n_dead_tup< 1000 
    ;

  LOOP
        
    FETCH Cur_upd_text INTO t_simulation_Before, t_value ;-- assignin results from select to variables
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    IF v_exec = 'Y' THEN  -- executing statments 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Statment to EXECUTE %, n_dead_tup %',t_simulation_Before, t_value; 
        EXECUTE t_simulation_Before; -- Execute dynamic SQL
    ELSE    
        RAISE NOTICE 'Statment to EXECUTE %, n_dead_tup %',t_simulation_Before, t_value;  -- use this is want to check what variable holds
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  CLOSE Cur_upd_text; -- close and deallocate cursor
  
END
$$;```
````

Comment: please specify postgres version you are using

Comment: @filiprem I am using 9.6. version. but looks like it is Postgres limitations and ill have to do something else to execute this vacuum, probably bash

Comment: yes, this needs some scripting or maybe use `vacuumdb` program instead.